# javascript declaring, and inserting to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I now multi-dimensional array in javascript is a bit silly. But in my program I have to use it.
I want to declare a dynamic 3 columns and m-rows array using javascript and then in a loop i need to insert some element to that array.  finally i want to display that array.

```
   var x = new Array();
    for (var y=0; y<=counter; y++) {
    x[y] = new Array (3);
x[y][0]='a';
x[y][1]='b';
x[y][2]='c';
    }
```

your help is highly appreciated ...

Comment: plase provide some code... what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrays grow as needed and so there is no point in declaring the length of the array. what you started with is fine.
http://books.google.ca/books?id=4RChxt67lvwC&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=JS+array+grow+as+needed?&source=bl&ots=tgY8BlGXm8&sig=_3jcH1LTmYi9QiXxn9pHROpbN1s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7v60T_XwA4ThggfGuoEX&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=JS%20array%20grow%20as%20needed%3F&f=false

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=5198

just a heads up it will create an array that is 1 bigger then counter. this is b/c in your for loop you have y<=counter and y starting at 0. if you want the length to be counter change it to

```
    y<counter
```

in order to display the array you might want to consider a for nested loop.

JS

```
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
  for (var j=0; j<3; j++)
    alert(x[i][j]);
```

where x is the reference to the array.
if you want to print the entire array at once consider creating a string from the elements in the array and print that

```
function displayArray(x){
var stringArray='';
 for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
  for (var j=0; j<3; j++)
    stringArray+= x[i][j];
 alert(stringArray);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var x = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4,5,6]
    ],
    [
        [7, 8, 9]
    ]   
];

alert(x[0][1][2]);
```

This is one reason why JavaScript's variable syntax isn't always what it's cracked up to be. Compare to Java:

```
String[][][] x = new String[5][5][5];
```

Comment: There are two errors included in this answer. First the TO wants a dynamic approach for declaring the array. Second the comparison with Java is absolutley useless

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
var sDataArray=MultiDimensionalArray(7,2); 
alert(sDataArray[0][0]); 

function MultiDimensionalArray(iRows,iCols) 
{ 
var i; 
var j; 
   var a = new Array(iRows); 
   for (i=0; i < iRows; i++) 
   { 
       a[i] = new Array(iCols); 
       for (j=0; j < iCols; j++) 
       { 
           a[i][j] = ""; 
       } 
   } 
   return(a); 
}
```

Being dynamic in rows maybe you want a list of arrays? You can also do a method to add a line, and increase the array size.

Answer (score 0):

```
try something like this..

var cols = 3;
var rows = 5;

createArray(cols,rows);

function createArray(cols,rows) {
    var newArray = [];
    for(i=0;i<cols;i++) {
        newArray[i] = [];
        for(j=0;j<rows;j++) {       
            newArray[i][j] = "["+i+"]"+"["+j+"]";
        }

    }   
    return newArray;
}
```